# How to stop an avaudioplayernode set to loop indefinitely at the end of current loop

Tags: swift, avaudioplayernode

Im using an `AVAudioPlayerNode` to loop playback of an audio file in buffer and need to be able to switch to the next track when the user clicks next but switch at the end of the loop instead of as soon as the user clicks next

Here's the code I use to start playback

```
if loopPlayback == true {  
    audioPlayer.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil, options: .loops, completionHandler: nil)
    audioPlayer.play()
    playPauseToggleState()  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferOptions.interruptsAtLoop` option in the `options` argument of `AVAudioPlayer`'s `scheduleBuffer` function. Here is an example:

```
self.player.scheduleBuffer(self.buffer, at: nil, options: [.interruptsAtLoop, .loops])
```

This line of code schedules a buffer to be played in loop forever. If there is something already playing, it is interrupted as soon as it finishes a loop iteration. Otherwise, playback starts now. Of course, I'm assuming the player node is currently playing.